# Why does Y do the same thing as yy?

Tags: vim

I've been using vim for several months now and I've gotten used to using C and D to change and delete everything from the cursor to the end of the line.

Consider the line below where the cursor is on the 'b' in 'bar':

```
foo.bar("hello world")
```

Hitting D at this point will yield:

```
foo.
```

While hitting C will do the same plus start insert mode with the cursor after the period.

However, pressing Y doesn't do the intuitively similar thing (copying everything from the cursor to the end of the line). Instead, it copies the entire line (just like yy).

How do I make Y copy the characters from the cursor to the end of the line instead of copying the entire line like yy?

Comment: This question has also been asked [on the vi/Vim stack exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6061/4676); you may find the answers there more helpful as they better address the *"why"*, rather than merely the *"how to adjust it"* which is covered here.

Comment: neovim has changed this default behaviour so in neovim uppercase Y yanks to end of line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nmap Y y$`

Does that do what you want?

*EDIT*

The reason why Y does the same thing as yy probably has something to do with this:

```
{Visual}["x]y           Yank the highlighted text [into register x] (for
                        {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not in Vi}

                                                        *v_Y*
{Visual}["x]Y           Yank the highlighted lines [into register x] (for
                        {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not in Vi}
```

Y is meant to act on lines, y is meant to act on individual characters?

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why `Y` doesn't behave the same way as `C` and `D`?

Comment: @advait See edit. Really not sure though. Brian might be right - might just be for historical reasons.

Answer (score 10):

From [this configuration](http://dotfiles.org/~amartini51/.vimrc):

```
" make Y effect to end of line instead of whole line
map Y y$
```

I suspect the default behaviour is simply due to some historical inconsistency.